# ACM ICPC crash practice

Tags: algorithm

I am selected for the ACM ICPC regional finals .But I have only 1 week of preparation left for me. I have prepared for it for 1 year but due to my exams  I could not spend much time in programming in the last two weeks.

**Can some one post some links where I can find problem sets covering all the important topics for practice along with the solutions so that I can revise well** . Ofcourse I know there are ACM ICPC past archives but they do not have solutions with them .

Also please suggest me some good links where I can find resource material to study also.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need solutions to practice for ICPC. You rarely ever obtain reference solutions. Just solve problems and let online judges test your solutions.

Here are some helpful web resources:

- TopCoder Algorithm: http://www.topcoder.com/tc
- SPOJ Onlinejudge: http://www.spoj.pl/
- Online Judge in Valladolid: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/
- Popular Book: Programming Challenges, http://www.programming-challenges.com/
- http://www.acmsolver.org/

Comment: I know all these .. As I told , I need some ready materials and problem set which helps me revise and go through everything quickly...And I want to go confident in the finals

Answer (score 2):

I have been taking part in ACM ICPC for three years. There is no shortcut to go if you want to be an excellent ACMer.Below is some website I improve myself. I think you can find something useful.

1. http://codeforces.com  (many smart guy share their code and competition is fun.)
2. http://train.usaco.org/usacogate (good train)
3. http://poj.org/  (Many Chinese ACMer start from this site.)

Comment: Again as I said, I need something to brush up my skills .I am active member in two of the above links..

Answer (score 0):

Congrats :)

You can overview the following books

1. Competitive Programming
2. From Baylor to Baylor
3. Programming Challenge

Above mentioned books can be useful to categorize the given problems and help you to develop ideas about how to solve those.A handy google search can get you a list of websites providing some common problems and their solutions targeting ACM ICPC.